# Log4Appender with RemoteSyslogAppender

Tags: .net, log4net-appender

I have created my custom RemoteSyslogAppender using below code

```
public class RemoteLogAppender : RemoteSyslogAppender
{
     protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
     {
         this.RemoteAddress = IPAddress.Parse("My Ip Address(10.10.10.10"); 
         this.RemotePort = 514;
         this.Facility = SyslogFacility.Audit;

         var bytearray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Log Remote Error")
         this.Client.Send(bytearray, bytearray.Length
     }
}
```

Here is test code to call Append method

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Logger));

LoggingEvent loggingEvent;
Log.Logger.Log(loggingEvent);
```

here I am expecting, Append method should gets called and send message to remote server. But Append never called

Please let me know I am doing anything wrong here and help me how to use the  RemoteSyslogAppender

Thanks-

Comment: I'm fairly certain the syslogappender is only functional on non-windows systems IE mono on Linux.